# matlab histogram plotting: setting specific x-axis label

Tags: matlab, histogram

I have a `data.txt` that is 16 by 16, and I want to plot into histogram plots for frequency counts:

```
cd C:\User\Aisk_000\Desktop\A\NC\Subjects\2414A\
A = dlmread('data.txt');

% Upper tri, removing 0's and repeated values
% Histogram plots
a = triu(A)
a=a'
a(a==0) = []
aA = a

histogram(aA)
title('Normal count distribution')
```

Currently the x-axis is set to a number of bins, but is there a way to set each point of the x-axis to it's corresponding value? Like the first point of x-axis will be called (1,1), and the second point be (1,2)... and so on. Since I used the `triu` function, there should be 120 points on the x-axis, while the y-axis still remains as the frequency count. This graph will allow me to get more spatial information out of it.

**I checked the histogram properties on the website but got really confused as to which one I should be using

Comment: So, you want to get the frequency of each bin and you want to access to the bin by var(1,1) etc? is that correct?

Comment: I wanted the actual x-axis to have labels at each point like (1,1), (1,2),(1,3).. and so on. As for the y-axis, it will be a set of numbers that the value of (1,1) will fall into. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Essentially, I want the actual points on x-axis (for example, (1,1) is the first cell in the 16 x 16 matrix), and y-axis just being the value from (1,1). Sorry English isn't my first language if I cannot explain well

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following:

```
nbin = 30;
[y,x] = hist(aA, nbin);
plot(x,y); 
ylim([0, max(y)])
```

`y` will be the number of elements in each bin, and `x` will be the center of each bin. You can access the first bin by `x(1)` and its frequency will be `y(1)/sum(y)` or `y(1)/numel(aA)`. Note that I set the number of bins (`nbin`) to 30 in the code above.